# lerna add : No packages found where <package> can be added

Tags: npm-install, yarnpkg, lerna

have added lerna to my project, i have added a package to my server by running this command successfully:

```
 lerna add  @types/express --dev
```

But when I want to add another one:

```
lerna add graphql class-validator type-graphql
```

I got this error :

```
info cli using local version of lerna
lerna notice cli v3.22.1
lerna WARN No packages found where graphql can be added.
```

1. Is something missed or wrong for adding the packages?
2. Should I use `yarn add` instead of `leran add`? looks it works but I doubt about the packages tree form to be correct

Answer (score 15, accepted):

At the moment, lerna doesn't support adding multiple packages to another package like so:

```
❌ lerna add '@my-company/{utils,types}' --scope '@my-company/ui' 

// We have to do this instead
lerna add '@my-company/utils' --scope '@my-company/ui' 
lerna add '@my-company/types' --scope '@my-company/ui'
```

Lerna does support adding 1 package into multiple packages though:

```
lerna add '@my-company/utils --scope '@my-company/{ui,data}'
```

lerna's github discussion on this issue for updates ([link](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/2004))

Answer (score 10):

Lerna add does not support multiple packages, try doing one at a time.

```
lerna add graphql
lerna add class-validator
lerna add type-graphql
```

There is an issue to support this on [github](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/2004) that will hopefully be resolved one day

Comment: it's weird that I can add type dependencies as mentioned, but having the same error while adding a package, I just tried `lerna add express-graphql`

Comment: I am not sure, I do not use type script.  The only difference I can see is that @types is an org package where as the others are single packages?

Comment: This is a super-confusing message from Lerna. I thought I'm typing the `--scope`'s name wrong, but I was actually trying to add multiple packages at once, that was the issue

Answer (score 4):

Foreword: The `lerna` `cli` is notoriously bad at giving feedback. You get weird errors and warnings that don't seem to make a lot of sense in the context.

## Why is this happening?

I identified the following causes (at one point or another) to all result in this error message:

1. You already added the package to given package.

   - This is somewhat irritating, since with `yarn` and `npm` you can (force) re-install a package, instead of having it error out.
2. You tried to add multiple packages in one command (this is also mentioned in other answers and comments here).

   - e.g.: `npx lerna add --scope=... packageA packageB`
   - NOTE: This is [an open issue in the lerna repo](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/2004#issuecomment-711303401). Workarounds are discussed there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I ran into the same issue with `"lerna": "^5.5.2"` trying to only install a single dependency.

Ran `lerna repair --verbose` and it highlighted issues with the version of Nx. Once fixed I could install deps again. Granted, you might not have Nx integrated, but the repair command will give you more insights into what could potentially be the issue.

As per @Domi's answer Lerna's CLI is still not very forthcoming with feedback.