# TS Error for Luxon DateTime: Cannot use namespace 'DateTime' as a type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, luxon

I've imported both luxon and types/luxon and whenever I try and set the type to luxons 'DateTime' object I get the error `DateTime: Cannot use namespace 'DateTime' as a type`.

Here is some example code of setting the type to DateTime when the error occurs with DateTime being highlighted in red.

```
interface CalendarForMessagesProps {
  messages: MessageType[];
  initialDate: DateTime;
}
...
const [visibleDate, setVisibleDate] = useState<DateTime>(initialDate || DateTime.now());
```

Do I need to do anything else for TS to accept DateTime as a valid type?

Comment: How are you importing `DateTime`?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, did you forget to install type?

npm

```
npm install --save-dev @types/luxon
```

yarn

```
yarn add -D @types/luxon
```

and now you can import DateTime type in your file.

```
import { DateTime } from "luxon";

interface CalendarForMessagesProps {
  initialDate: DateTime;
}
```

Comment: We're using lerna to add dependancies and apparently lerna doesn't support adding multiple packages to another packages which might be the reason this isn't working for me since when i try and add it I get the error 'No packages found where @types/luxon can be added.'. So my answer might be within here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62980752/lerna-add-no-packages-found-where-package-can-be-added